# doit.am 4-way motor & 16-way servo shield board not working with adafruit libraries

Tags: arduino, adafruit, servo

Got a servo + motor driver arduino shield with a robotic arm chassis from amazon. Found this link on the web :

https://github.com/SmartArduino/SZDOITWiKi/wiki/2-4ch-DC-motor-%26amp%3B-16ch-servo-shield---motor-and-servo-shield

Not enough details to help me control servos/ motors for my own project.
Tried the libraries given in the answer to this question:

[doit 2-way motor & 16-way servo shield board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327327/doit-2-way-motor-16-way-servo-shield-board)

The libraries have been included, but i can't figure out how to use it properly. Ran the sample code as given in the adafruit website :

https://learn.adafruit.com/16-channel-pwm-servo-driver/using-the-adafruit-library

The 0th channel didn't move the servo as expected so I don't know what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, here's the complete reply, with some precautions for future users.
The shield can be used via the library available at https://learn.adafruit.com/16-channel-pwm-servo-driver/using-the-adafruit-library.
(Shoutout to @djsfantasi ).
NOTE : One of the main things to ensure is that the 5v power supply for the servos must be separate from that of the arduino, as it messes up the servos somehow.

The motors can be powered via the given slots on the shield. All you have to do is supply the DIR and PWM values to the 1st 8 available arduino pins (after pin 0 and 1, ie, 2-9). It is pretty easy to figure out which pin controls which channel.
NOTE: Since the motor pins are available via male headers stacked very close together, i would suggest using female headers/jumper wires before connecting them to your motors. I burned my 1st shield's motor driver due to the +ve and -ve ending up shorted together.

Thanks for the replies everyone and best of luck to you guys reading this.